# Azure DevOps Custom ServiceHook

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, webhooks

I am looking for a way to send a custom HTTP POST on service hook action. Kind of like the default WebHook functionality but with a customised body.

Is there a way to link a custom action to the consumer event?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some proxy like azure function that will reformat your message and if need call Azure DevOps rest api and also get more information, and after reformatting message you send it to final consumer. You can use logic app also for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure logic app as suggested by @Janusz Nowak to send a custom http post on the event in azure devops.
You can check out [Quickstart: Create your first workflow by using Azure Logic Apps - Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow).

After the logic app is created in your azure portal. In the L**ogic app designer** page choose the **Blank Logic App** in templates.

> In the search box type in **azure devops** and select a **trigger** event in azure devops.

[image]

Then you will be prompted to authorize the logic app to connect to your azure devops.

> When you complete configuring your organization and project in the event trigger. Click ** + New Step** to add a **HTTP action**

[image]

You can customize your Http Request in the Http action.

[image]

Comment: That looks very promising. I will dig into this! Thanks

Comment: Hi @user3475441 Did above steps work out for you? Please let me know if there is any questions.